# How to run a server side JS

Tags: javascript, server-side

I have a little question here. Is there any way to build a server side JS without any use of external software. The reason for this is I am not able to install any software on the webspace but I wanted to experiment with realtime communication with the server and another user for a game or something like this.

If someone knows a way to establish something like this I would be quite happy to hear about it.

EDIT: Guys NOT NodeJS **I AM NOT ALLOWED TO INSTALL ANY OTHER SOFTWARE!**

Comment: I was experimenting with this concept today. I would recommend NodeJs with Socket.IO. Check out [this tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) for a basic chat room

Comment: But nodeJS is another software, wich I am not allowed to install ....

Comment: @Feirell then no, you can't. Javascript doesn't do server-side out of the box, its a scripting language for writing client side code for web browsers

Comment: There's no magic way to get software to run on a machine that doesn't already have support for the programming environment you want to use.

Comment: Wait,  so your question is how to run JavaScript without any software?

Comment: @dave yeah ok it is not possible I know, I though it might be able to load it with the apache server or something like this but ok ... :( it is not possible

Comment: If you can install mods for Apache, there are [some](http://www.wxjavascript.net/mod_wxjs/) [options](http://www.modjs.org/) though they're probably not as capable and usable as much as the alternative (Node, etc.)

Comment: I am not sure if I can I just though through .htaccess or another document you could direct apache to load a js as a responder for request

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/
or

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

Those $15 a year webhosts typically don't allow you advanced customization. You need a better web hosting service that allows you CLI access to the server back end.

Answer (score 0):

Running JavaScript on backend requires NodeJS runtime environment. Download it here https://nodejs.org/en/

Alternatively you can can configure an instance on Heroku and run your application there. But I would suggest to try the first one.

Answer (score 0):

No. Javascript is a scripting language that was designed to work within the browser. There's no out of the box solution for you, as Javascript doesn't do server-side out of the box

However, [Node.Js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (and others) use Chrome's V8 engine to create an event-driven runtime environment which can allow writing server-side code with Javascript. That's your best option

Comment: Why did you removed your previous answer ? It was nice for people looking for something else.

Comment: @Feirell I didn't remove it, I edited it. I can edit back what I wrote. I just thought this was the more proper answer as you added that you can't use Node Js. I'll edit that part back in